# Triggering methods in Obj c

Tags: iphone

I would like to detect taps with a tapRecognizer in one class that triggers another class to create an object of a third class.

How Can I trigger this method from the tap detecting class without creating a new object of the second class?

Or would creating a new object of this second class be fine? It would lose all of its old data though.

How is triggering like this done? I tried something but it just warned about an object is being accessed in a class method.

e.g.

```
ViewController Class 1
+(void) setupClass2
{
 Class2 class = .........
 class.someValue = ......
 self.navigationController pushViewController:class ......
}

// The calling/trigger class should be able to invoke the setupClass function e.g.
[Class1 setupClass];
```

How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a protocol with methods like this:

```
-(void) class1:(Class1*) c didReceivedTouch:(UITouch*) e; //or any other params that you need
```

Then you assign a delegate that conforms to that protocol (class 2 in your case). Create the class 3 object in that callback.

Comment: Could you explain a little more please. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare a protocol with method suggested by Max

@protocol UrProtocolName 
@required/@optional
-(void) class1:(Class1*) c didReceivedTouch:(UITouch*) e; //or any other params that you need

@end

Then implement the protocol in your second class

@interface 2ndClass < UrProtocolName>

```
.....
```

@end

@implementation 2ndClass

-(void) class1:(Class1*) c didReceivedTouch:(UITouch*) e
{
 3rdClass class = .........
 self.navigationController pushViewController:class animated:YES];
}
@end

But I really don't understand why do you want to gor for 2nd Class, when all you want is to create object of 3rdClass and push it on navigationController. You can have 2ndClass' object as a member of firstClass initialized while constructing the object of 2ndClass, and den you can have one method in 2ndClass which will simple create an object of 3rdClass, and you can call this method of 2ndClass object as many times, till your firstClass object is in scope.